# Converting a 4 byte ip address to standard dotted decimal notation

Tags: c, string, ip-address

If I have a 4 byte address stored in char address[4] and the contents are:

```
address[0] = '\x80';
address[1] = '\xAB';
address[2] = '\x0A';
address[3] = '\x1C';

// all together: 80 AB 0A 1C
```

I want to convert it to a character array that looks like "128.171.10.28", since 80 in hex is 128, AB in hex is 171 and so on.

How can I do this?

Comment: "Converting a 4 byte ip address in hex to a character array" is the wrong question to ask - it's already a "character array". What you mean is that you want to get a textual representation in the standard dotted decimal ip notation. Subject changed accordingly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
char saddr[16];
sprintf(saddr, "%d.%d.%d.%d", (unsigned char)address[0], (unsigned char)address[1], (unsigned char)address[2], (unsigned char)address[3]);
```

or

```
char saddr[16];
unsigned char *addr = (unsigned char*)address;

sprintf(saddr, "%d.%d.%d.%d", addr[0], addr[1], addr[2], addr[3]);
```

or, as pointed out by dreamlax:

```
char saddr[16];
sprintf(saddr, "%hhu.%hhu.%hhu.%hhu", address[0], address[1], address[2], address[3]);
```

Comment: `%hhu` would be a better specifier for each address component, since that is exactly what you are giving `sprintf`.

Comment: Your cast is wrong. You need to cast to `unsigned char *` **before** dereferencing the pointer, not afterwards. Doing it afterwards has implementation-defined behavior which could raise a signal or convert incorrectly (on non-twos-complement systems).

Comment: And of course it would be better to just use the right type (`unsigned char [4]` or `uint8_t [4]`) to begin with.

Answer (score 5):

An IP address ist just the individual octets printed as decimal separated by a .

```
  printf("%d.%d.%d.%d",address[0],address[1],address[2],address[3]);
```

You probably should make your `char address[4]` an `unsigned char address[4]`

Comment: I don't need to print it out though. I need the entire address to be stored in another char array that contains the characters {1,2,8,.,1,7,1,.,1,0,.,2,8}

Comment: This gives "-128" for the first char, unless you change the array type to `unsigned char` as recommended.

Comment: @MikeU: look up the function that prints a string into a variable. Also, strings are char arrays

Answer (score -1):

Using %u would be even better.

Comment: That gives a 'stack smashing detected' error, compiling with gcc.

Comment: %u should only be used for unsigned data - that message means the sprintf buffer overflowed which probably means your types didn't agree.

Comment: Martin - not my types, but the types used in the question. `%u` expects `unsigned int` values.